# Impressão da lista duplamente encadeada na ordem inversa

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Bom dia, esse é o meu primeiro post aqui no Stack Overflow. Eu estava tentando fazer com que uma lista duplamente encadeada seja impressa na ordem inversa. Porém, após percorrer essa lista de forma inversa, produziu o resultado de forma inesperada. O meu código está imprimindo mais do que o necessário. Segue o print em anexo e o código fonte.

Conto com a ajuda de vocês!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Exercício: Inserir  células na lista duplamente encadeada e em seguida imprimí-las na ordem inversa


typedef struct cel{

    struct cel* ant;
    int conteudo;
    struct cel* prox;

}celula;


celula* criaLista(){
    return NULL;
}

celula* insereInicioLista(celula* inicio, int valor){

    celula* novo = (celula*)malloc(sizeof(celula));

    //Inicialmente os ponteiros ini e fim apontam para NULL
    celula* ini = inicio;
    celula* fim = inicio;


    if(novo == NULL){
        printf("Memoria insuficiente\n");
        exit(1);

    } else if(verificaListaVazia(inicio)){

        novo->conteudo = valor;
        novo->prox = fim;
        novo->ant = ini;

        fim = novo;
        ini = novo;

        return ini;

    } else {

        novo->conteudo = valor;
        novo->prox = fim;
        fim->ant = novo;
        ini = novo;

        return ini;
    }
}

int verificaListaVazia(celula* lista){
    return lista == NULL;
}


void imprimeLista(celula* lista){

    celula* p = lista;

    for(; p != NULL; p = p->prox){
        printf("%d-> ", p->conteudo);
//      printf("valor: %d\n", p->conteudo);
//      printf("Endereco de p: %p\n", p);
//      printf("Endereco do prox de p: %p\n", p->prox);
//      printf("Endereco anterior a p: %p\n\n", p->ant);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}

void imprimeListaNaOrdemInversa(celula* inicio){

    celula* p = inicio; //Ponteiro que aponta para o início da lista

    while(p->prox != NULL){
        p = p->prox;
    }

    //Ao final, p passa a apontar para o último nó
    celula* final = p;

    for(; final != NULL; final = final->ant){
        printf(" <- %d", final->conteudo);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    celula* lista = (celula*)malloc(sizeof(celula));

    if(lista == NULL){
        printf("Memoria insuficiente\n");
        exit(1);

    } else {

        lista = criaLista();

        lista = insereInicioLista(lista, 10);
        lista = insereInicioLista(lista, 20);
        lista = insereInicioLista(lista, 30);
        lista = insereInicioLista(lista, 40);
        lista = insereInicioLista(lista, 50);

        printf("LISTA DUPLAMENTE ENCADEADA\n");
        imprimeLista(lista);

        printf("LISTA DUPLAMENTE ENCADEADA INVERSA\n");
        imprimeListaNaOrdemInversa(lista);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rodei seu código aqui e não apresentou erro.

Comment: Na verdade o problema é que a lista está sendo impressa aparecendo os números aleatórios (lixo de memória) depois de imprimir os valores válidos que eu passei para a função.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está apenas na função `insereInicioLista` que tem algumas coisas incorretas.

O ponteiro `fim` não é necessário uma vez que se está a inserir no inicio sempre, e se fosse seria necessário percorrer a lista até ao fim para que ficasse a apontar para o nó certo.

O principal ponto que faz falhar é não ser atribuído o `novo->ant` no `else`, aqui:

```
else {

    novo->conteudo = valor;
    novo->prox = fim;
    fim->ant = novo;
    ini = novo;

    return ini;
}
```

O que faz com que fique indefinido, e que a navegação vá pela memória fora, acedendo a endereços aleatórios. Este deveria ser atribuído com 
`NULL`, como foi na parte do `if`.

Existem também algumas simplificações no código que se podem fazer, como por exemplo, nos retornos:

```
    ini = novo;

    return ini;

} else {

    ...
    ini = novo;

    return ini;
}
```

Aqui vemos que o valor a ser retornado é sempre o `novo`, então será mais fácil retornar diretamente `novo` e fora do `if` pois é igual nos dois casos.

Corrigindo e simplificando a função `insereInicioLista` fica assim:

```
celula* insereInicioLista(celula* inicio, int valor){

    celula* novo = (celula*)malloc(sizeof(celula));

    //testa logo se conseguiu obter memoria, antes de fazer mais coisas como tinha antes
    if(novo == NULL){ 
        printf("Memoria insuficiente\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //a construção dos ponteiros do novo não depende se a lista está vazia, logo 
    //pode ser feita fora do if
    novo->conteudo = valor; 
    novo->prox = inicio;
    novo->ant = NULL;

    if (!verificaListaVazia(inicio)){ //ou if (inicio != NULL) que era mais simples
       inicio->ant = novo; //se existe lista colocar o ant do primeiro a apontar para o novo
    }

    return novo;
}
```

Aproveito também para mencionar que a função criarLista que tem:

```
celula* criaLista(){
    return NULL;
}
```

Não faz muito sentido, pois retorna sempre `NULL`. Seria mais simples e claro trocar no seu `main` a inicialização para:

```
lista = NULL;
```